# Votes for "that fixed my problem"

Tags: feature-request

Instead of just having a single accepted answer, and other upvoted answers, I personally would find it helpful to see what answers have solved other users' bugs or errors.

Kind of like how Amazon.com has the "Was this review helpful to you?" buttons in the customer reviews.  This way when browsing through questions similar to the problem I am having at any given time, I can see which answers other users found useful in solving their similar problem.

Comment: 4 downvotes in a matter of seconds without any comment as to why...

Comment: [Votes on Meta are different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87475/add-a-note-about-downvoting-on-meta)

Comment: ...meaning that, more than likely, people think your suggested feature is a not a good one, not that there's anything wrong with your question.

Answer (score 10):

> I can see which answers other users found useful in solving their similar problem.

That's what upvotes are for.

Comment: Not entirely, as not everyone who has upvoted an answer has had this problem and used that answer as a solution

Comment: @DanF So you want a "Me too thanks!" button or similar? What for?

Comment: Maybe they haven't used it to solve their issue, but they thought it was valuable either way. That should say enough. Without them having to deal with that specific issue they can still judge the quality of it when they are known in that specific field.

Comment: Sometimes implementing a solution suggested in an answer can be a time consuming process.  Knowing in advance that someone else has had this similar problem, and used this particular implementation suggested to solve their problem can be a way of deciding which implementations to try first

Comment: @DanF: That's what comments are for.