# Answer converted to comment, what happened?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905530/why-does-the-font-lucida-sans-unicode-render-differently-in-ie9-and-chrome) had an answer that for some reason suddenly appeared as a comment on my question. All the comments on the answer also got added to my question.

The comment that originally was an answer is the third comment ("You should reset all CSS..." - by Vector).

Is this a bug?

Comment: It wasn't really an answer to the question (the question being 'why is this happening'), but was useful information so would have been converted to a comment instead to preserve the useful information, but retaining the actual Answer aspect of the questions for posts that explicitly answer the question.

Comment: Why the downvote..?

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's worth reading this: [Downvotes work differently on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87475/add-a-note-about-downvoting-on-meta)

Comment: @JonW Thank you (for both answers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was flagged by a user as "not an answer", seeing as it was a single line.

A moderator saw the flag and converted the answer to a comment, which is what it should have been in the first place.

Comment: Okay.. It probably wasn't the best answer in the world, but converting it to a comment only caused confusion (at least for me) since I couldn't find an explanation anywhere for what happened.

Comment: @Stian - Well, now you know. We do have standards, and that answer was sub-standard.

Comment: Well, isn't that what the down vote function is for? Anyway, my main gripe here is that I couldn't see anywhere why the answer suddenly was a comment, so it would be nice if the comment could be flagged with "Answer converted to comment" or something, then I wouldn't have to ask why it happened in the first place. Thanks for the help anyway! :)

Comment: @Stian downvoting may be appropriate as well, but in this case, the response was truely not an answer (it was a comment), so it should have been changed.  Downvotes work better for true answers that are not accurate.  The other answer on your question is not much better as it is barely more than a link-only answer.